# Connect to MySQL DataBase File

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

I have a issue. I have to have a MySQL Database File inside a NetBeans project files. I don't know how to write that kind of connection, and I don't know if it is posible.

My need is similar to have a SQLite database file, but instead I need that the database be a MySQL database.

So, How I do have to write the connection?

Comment: Google `JDBC MySQL Connector`.

Comment: I will rewrite the question, because I know how to connect a MySQL database with Java, but I don't how to connect a database **FILE** that came from MySQL and it's inside of Java project files. I think that this question it's not a duplication, because the answer that you point doesn't fulfill my needs.